# How to find out which person contributed in all years-query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new in SQL and I've got a query which I can't really figure it out.
So I've got 3 tables
One called "Filme" which translates as movies
[image: first table]

One called "Cineasti" which translates as filmmaker
[image: table 2]

And third one called "Premii_obtinute" which means "Awards"
[image: table 3]

I need to figure out which Filmmaker(Cineast) who participated in the making of films throughout the years (all years for which films were released)
I tried something like

```
SELECT c1.numecineast AS numecineast
FROM cineaști c1
EXCEPT
SELECT numecineast
FROM
    (SELECT numecineast FROM cineaști) numecineast
        CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT AnLansare
     FROM filme f1) Anlansare (year)
WHERE numecineast || ' - ' || year NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT c1.numecineast || ' - ' || AnLansare
    FROM cineaști c1
        inner join premii_obținute p1 on p1.codcineast=c1.codcineast
    inner join filme f1 on f1.codfilm=p1.codfilm)
```

and

```
FROM cineaști c1
EXCEPT
SELECT numecineast
FROM
    (SELECT numecineast FROM cineaști) numecineast
        CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT AnLansare
     FROM filme f1) Anlansare (year)
WHERE numecineast || ' - ' || year NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT c1.numecineast || ' - ' || AnLansare
    FROM cineaști c1
        inner join premii_obținute p1 on p1.codcineast=c1.codcineast
    inner join filme f1 on f1.codfilm=p1.codfilm)
```

or even

```
SELECT c1.numecineast AS numecineast
FROM cineaști c1
EXCEPT
SELECT numecineast
FROM
    (SELECT numecineast FROM cineaști) numecineast
        CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT AnLansare
     FROM filme f1) Anlansare (year)
WHERE numecineast || ' - ' || year NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT c1.numecineast || ' - ' || AnLansare
    FROM cineaști c1
        inner join premii_obținute p1 on p1.codcineast=c1.codcineast
    inner join filme f1 on f1.codfilm=p1.codfilm)
```

But none of them seem to give the right result. If you could help me I would appreciate it because I'm new to SQL and I don't have any other idea. Thank you

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.  `Union` does not seem like a likely operation for this query.

Comment: You've edited your question and made it completely different from the original. Rather than doing this you should ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the number to a string so that the types match:

```
with year_release as(
    select distinct year_release::text
    from movie m1
        inner join awards a1 on a1.moviecod=m1.moviecod
        inner join actors ac1 on ac1.actorcod=a1.actorcod
    order by 1
),
    Actors as (
    select actorname
    from actors
    )
select * from year_release
union
select * from actors
```

Comment: Just to add some context for Eisotopius:  Union is like stacking one data set on top of another.  The final resulting column needs to be all of a single data type, but if you stack numeric data like `year_release` on top of character data like `actorname`, then the database can't figure out what you want it to be.  Bob's answer here makes it so when the Union happens, it's stacking character data on top of character data, so it knows the resulting field should be character data as well.